# POWERBI DAX_Combining Filter, Rank and Sumx

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, rank

Below, I have the following table in which I need to evaluate incidents for individual segments. It is always in the format CW. 1-191, I evaluate incidents; CW. 1-192, I evaluate incidents; CW. 1-193, I evaluate incidents.

[sc3_olt_im_f_incident](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acYOJ.png)

Within this range, there are duplicates and sometimes multiple different values for a single incident. Based on the first value, I need to take the most current one (max of first value)  and count the final identification only once. For example, within the range CW. 1-193, I need to count the final identification for incident 5352 as 1, not 2, even though we have the same incident with max(First value) occurring 2 times; I don't want duplicates there.

At the end of all this, I need to filter by department. The result will be a column graph where the X-axis represents the ranges 1-191, 1-192, 1-193, etc., and the Y-axis represents the count of incidents according to the aforementioned conditions.

Based on the provided table (if I do not filter department), the result should be:

• For the range 1-191, the result would be 1 (i.e., incident 6343).

• For the range 1-192, the result would be 1 (i.e., incident 5352).

• For the range 1-193, the result would be 1 (i.e., incident 5352).

What I'm struggling with is nesting the calculation conditions for a given segment within the filter. Could you please advise me?

Below, I'm sending 2 calculations that have come closest to the desired result, but ultimately didn't work.

Formula 1:

```dax
Deadline Alert = 
    VAR FilteredData =
        FILTER (
        ALL ( sc3_olt_im_f_incident ),
        sc3_olt_im_f_incident[CW Index]
            <= MAX ( sc3_olt_im_f_incident[CW Index] )
    )
VAR _SUMMARIZE =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FilteredData,
        sc3_olt_im_f_incident[incident_id],
        "MAXINDEX", CALCULATE ( MAX ( sc3_olt_im_f_incident[First value] ) ),
        "LATESTvalue",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK (sc3_olt_im_f_incident[Final identification]),
                FILTER ( FilteredData, sc3_olt_im_f_incident[First value] = MAX (sc3_olt_im_f_incident[First value] ) )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( _SUMMARIZE, [LATESTvalue] )
```

Formula 2:

```dax
Deadline Alert=

VAR MaxCWIndex = MAX ( sc3_olt_im_f_incident[CW Index] )
RETURN
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        ALL ( sc3_olt_im_f_incident ),
        sc3_olt_im_f_incident[CW Index] <= MaxCWIndex
            && sc3_olt_im_f_incident[Responsible Department by Group] = "Sales"
    ),
    IF (
        RANKX (
            FILTER (
                ALL ( sc3_olt_im_f_incident ),
                sc3_olt_im_f_incident[CW Index] <= MaxCWIndex
            ),
            sc3_olt_im_f_incident[First value],
            ,
            DESC,
            Dense
        ) = 1,
        sc3_olt_im_f_incident[Final identification]
    )
)
```

Comment: I suggest you include the sample data as a copiable table instead of an image.